# Why are my designs coming out pixelated with random color smudges around text/graphics?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anti-aliasing

I'm using illustrator CC 2017. I wanted to make an email signature. I made the dimensions 330x148px. (I would have used 600x220px but when I added it to my saved signatures it wouldn't let me resize it so I neeed it to be rather small).

What I'm seeing is pixelation and random smudged colors that seem like a haze on top of everything. It looks terrible. It is really evident in the space between text which should be completely white. Below is the JPG file I exported.

I found a vector file of a hex grid pattern and added it as a background.

I tried aligning the pixels to the pixel grid and didn't really see any change. When I view in pixel preview it looks bad as expected.

I exported it out as JPG, 72ppi, Baseline Compression, Anti-aliasing "Type Optimized", and quality 3.

After spending hours of research and countless thoughts of giving up I've decided to ask for help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Alton

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the quality to a higher number. Setting the number that low compresses the image and creates artifacts.

I would also suggest that you create your signature with text instead of using an image for the whole signature.

[Here is an example signature](https://jsfiddle.net/6atkgphn/1/)

Instead of using a background color in the table you would change that with a background image.